# Applying 3D Hover Effect to Multiple Divs

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have this jQuery 3D hover effect:
https://jsfiddle.net/qdc4v1jg/

The code works fine when it's applied to one div, but when it's applied to more than one div, it doesn't work.

I tried to get the code to work with multiple divs by:

- Changing all of the HTML & CSS div ID's to div classes
- Changing the jQuery code from "`document.getElementById('tilt')`" to "`document.getElementsByClassName('tilt')`"

However, none of these changes worked. As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/qdc4v1jg/1/

If anyone could help me out with this, I'd greatly appreciate it. Again, I just need this 3D hover effect to work with multiple divs (an unlimited amount).

Comment: Because getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements and the collection doesn't have an addEventListener method

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any way you could demonstrate this in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that's so cool! Correct me if I'm wrong, but getElementsByClassName returns an HTML collection, right? Wouldn't you need to turn it into an array and then use 'forEach' to add an event listener to each one?

P.S. You've probably got some of the best comments on your code I've seen on Stackoverflow (I'm new, so I obviously haven't seen much haha)

**EDIT:** Sorry it took a while for me to reply back! Here's the solution.
I've added comments to the changes I've made. I basically put the majority of your code under `forEach` so that everything is applied to EACH item in the array we created.

```js
/* Store the elements with class "tilt" in elements */
let elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tilt"));

/* For each 'item' in the "elements" array... */
elements.forEach((item) => {
  /* Assign each 'item' in the "elements" array to a variable called "el" */
  let el = item;

  /*
   * Add a listener for mousemove event
   * Which will trigger function 'handleMove'
   * On mousemove
   */
  el.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMove);

  /* Get the height and width of the element */
  const height = el.clientHeight;
  const width = el.clientWidth;

  /* Define function a */
  function handleMove(e) {
    /*
     * Get position of mouse cursor
     * With respect to the element
     * On mouseover
     */
    /* Store the x position */
    const xVal = e.layerX;
    /* Store the y position */
    const yVal = e.layerY;

    /*
     * Calculate rotation valuee along the Y-axis
     * Here the multiplier 20 is to
     * Control the rotation
     * You can change the value and see the results
     */
    const yRotation = 20 * ((xVal - width / 2) / width);

    /* Calculate the rotation along the X-axis */
    const xRotation = -20 * ((yVal - height / 2) / height);

    /* Generate string for CSS transform property */
    const string =
      "perspective(500px) scale(1.1) rotateX(" +
      xRotation +
      "deg) rotateY(" +
      yRotation +
      "deg)";

    /* Apply the calculated transformation */
    el.style.transform = string;
  }

  /* Add listener for mouseout event, remove the rotation */
  el.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    el.style.transform = "perspective(500px) scale(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0)";
  });

  /* Add listener for mousedown event, to simulate click */
  el.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    el.style.transform = "perspective(500px) scale(0.9) rotateX(0) rotateY(0)";
  });

  /* Add listener for mouseup, simulate release of mouse click */
  el.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    el.style.transform = "perspective(500px) scale(1.1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0)";
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Styles for the tilt block */
.tilt {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 50px auto;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, transform 0.1s;

  /*
     * Adding image to the background
     * No relation to the hover effect.
     */
  background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/300/200);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tilt:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div class="tilt">
    <!--  Container for our block  -->
  </div>

  <div class="tilt">
    <!--  Container for our block  -->
  </div>

  <div class="tilt">
    <!--  Container for our block  -->
  </div>
```

Comment: beat me to it. getElementsByClassName  returns an array. This will need to be looped through.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Is there any way you could demonstrate this in a jsFiddle? I'm not sure how to go about applying your suggestion as the code isn't mine. I found it online.

Comment: Hey! Sorry it took me a while to reply back, but I've edited my answer with the solution. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

- Simply move you Javascript to a function
- use `document.querySelectorAll('.tilt')` to create a list of elements
- remove `let el = document.getElementById('tilt')`
- loop the list of elements and attach the 'tilt' listeners to each element found

**CSS**

- Change all ID `#tilt` to class `.tilt`
- don't modify `<HTML>`, but use `<body>` or a `.wrapper` instead

**HTML**

- Add as many as 'tilt elements' as you like using `class="tilt"`

**Snippet** (go 'Full-page' view on SO)

```js
//Traverse an array and execute the passed callback function for each array element found
var forEachEntryIn = function (array, callback, scope) {
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); } };

// Create a list of 'tilted' element ojects 
var elList = document.querySelectorAll('.tilt');
// can be any comma delimited selector list, not just '.tilt'

// Attach the tilt listeners to the list of elements
forEachEntryIn(elList, function (idx,el,scope) { connectListener(el); } );

/* 
 * Packed original code in function connectListener()
 * parameter: element object to attach listenener to
 */
function connectListener(el) {

/* Store the element in el */
//let el = document.getElementById('tilt') // REMOVE

/* Get the height and width of the element */
const height = el.clientHeight;
const width = el.clientWidth;

    /*
      * Add a listener for mousemove event
      * Which will trigger function 'handleMove'
      * On mousemove
      */
    el.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);

    /* Define function a */
    function handleMove(e) {
      /*
        * Get position of mouse cursor
        * With respect to the element
        * On mouseover
        */
      /* Store the x position */
      const xVal = e.layerX;
      /* Store the y position */
      const yVal = e.layerY;
  
      /*
        * Calculate rotation valuee along the Y-axis
        * Here the multiplier 20 is to
        * Control the rotation
        * You can change the value and see the results
        */
      const yRotation = 20 * ((xVal - width / 2) / width);
  
      /* Calculate the rotation along the X-axis */
      const xRotation = -20 * ((yVal - height / 2) / height);
  
      /* Generate string for CSS transform property */
      const string = 'perspective(500px) scale(1.1) rotateX(' + xRotation + 'deg) rotateY(' + yRotation + 'deg)';
  
      /* Apply the calculated transformation */
      el.style.transform = string;
    }

    /* Add listener for mouseout event, remove the rotation */
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      el.style.transform = 'perspective(500px) scale(1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0)';
    });

    /* Add listener for mousedown event, to simulate click */
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      el.style.transform = 'perspective(500px) scale(0.9) rotateX(0) rotateY(0)';
    });

    /* Add listener for mouseup, simulate release of mouse click */
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      el.style.transform = 'perspective(500px) scale(1.1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0)';
    });
};
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center; /* CORRECTED, was 'align-contents' */
    height: 100%;
}
/*
    Changed all ID #tilt to Class .tilt 
*/
/* Styles for the tilt block */
.tilt {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 3rem auto; /* MOD from '0' to add some space */

    transition: box-shadow 0.1s, transform 0.1s;
  
    /*
        Adding image to the background
        No relation to the hover effect.
    */
    background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/300/200);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tilt:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="tilt"></div>
<div class="tilt"></div>
<div class="tilt"></div>
<div class="tilt"></div>
```